# Systemverilog - Register Chain Simulation Problem

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I wrote SystemVerilog code that gets an input and connects it to a chain of registers (i.e., a "word shift register").

The output is an array whose size equals the number of registers + 1.
The output's zero index is simply a wire that's driven by the input.
This is my code:

```
module register_chain
#(
    parameter NUMBER_REGISTERS = 31 ,
    parameter WIDTH_REGISTER = 12
)
(
    input INPUT_CLOCK ,
    input [ WIDTH_REGISTER - 1 : 0 ] INPUT_DATA ,
    input INPUT_ENABLE ,
    input INPUT_RESET ,

    output logic [ 0 : NUMBER_REGISTERS ] [ WIDTH_REGISTER - 1 : 0 ] OUTPUT_DATA
) ;

logic [ 0 : NUMBER_REGISTERS - 1 ] [ WIDTH_REGISTER - 1 : 0 ] array_registers_data ;

    assign OUTPUT_DATA = { INPUT_DATA , array_registers_data } ;
    
    always_ff @ ( posedge INPUT_CLOCK )
    begin : registering
        if ( INPUT_RESET == 1'b1 ) begin
            array_registers_data <= '{ default : '0 } ;
        end else if ( INPUT_ENABLE == 1'b1 ) begin
            array_registers_data <= { INPUT_DATA , array_registers_data [ 0 : NUMBER_REGISTERS - 2 ] } ;
        end
    end : registering

endmodule
```

I'm seeing very strange behavior in my simulator:

`OUTPUT_DATA[0]` is the same as the input `INPUT_DATA` (as it should be).

`OUTPUT_DATA[1]` is also the same as the input `INPUT_DATA` (which is a bug).

`OUTPUT_DATA` [ 2 ... n ] get the delayed copies of `INPUT_DATA` as they should.

Do you see something wrong in my code?

[image]

Comment: Show us your testbench. There's probably a subtle problem with how you're generating INPUT_DATA -- it may be changing *just before* the clock edge (rather than being driven by the clock), so it is captured essentially immediately by the register array.

Comment: INPUT_DATA is generated synchronously inside an always_ff block driven by the same INPUT_CLOCK as the register chain module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a bug in your simulator.  This testbench works on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/dyiN):

```
module register_chain
#(
    parameter NUMBER_REGISTERS = 31 ,
    parameter WIDTH_REGISTER = 12
)
(
    input INPUT_CLOCK ,
    input [ WIDTH_REGISTER - 1 : 0 ] INPUT_DATA ,
    input INPUT_ENABLE ,
    input INPUT_RESET ,

    output logic [ 0 : NUMBER_REGISTERS ] [ WIDTH_REGISTER - 1 : 0 ] OUTPUT_DATA
) ;

logic [ 0 : NUMBER_REGISTERS - 1 ] [ WIDTH_REGISTER - 1 : 0 ] array_registers_data ;

    assign OUTPUT_DATA = { INPUT_DATA , array_registers_data } ;
    
    always_ff @ ( posedge INPUT_CLOCK )
    begin : registering
        if ( INPUT_RESET == 1'b1 ) begin
            array_registers_data <= '{ default : '0 } ;
        end else if ( INPUT_ENABLE == 1'b1 ) begin
            array_registers_data <= { INPUT_DATA , array_registers_data [ 0 : NUMBER_REGISTERS - 2 ] } ;
        end
    end : registering

endmodule

module tb;
    parameter NUMBER_REGISTERS = 31;
    parameter WIDTH_REGISTER   = 12;

    bit INPUT_CLOCK;
    bit [WIDTH_REGISTER-1:0] INPUT_DATA;
    bit INPUT_ENABLE = 1;
    bit INPUT_RESET  = 1;
    wire [0:NUMBER_REGISTERS][WIDTH_REGISTER-1:0] OUTPUT_DATA;

register_chain #(
    .NUMBER_REGISTERS(NUMBER_REGISTERS),
    .WIDTH_REGISTER  (WIDTH_REGISTER)
)
dut (
    .INPUT_CLOCK   (INPUT_CLOCK),
    .INPUT_DATA    (INPUT_DATA),
    .INPUT_ENABLE  (INPUT_ENABLE),
    .INPUT_RESET   (INPUT_RESET),
    .OUTPUT_DATA   (OUTPUT_DATA)
);

always #5 INPUT_CLOCK++;

always_ff @ ( posedge INPUT_CLOCK ) begin
    INPUT_DATA <= $urandom;
end

always @ (negedge INPUT_CLOCK) begin
    if (!INPUT_RESET) begin
        $display($time, "  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='h%x, [1]='h%x", OUTPUT_DATA[0], OUTPUT_DATA[1]);
    end
end

initial begin
    #23 INPUT_RESET = 0;
    #100 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Here is some sample output I get, where `[0]` and `[1]` are different:

```
              30  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='h57f, [1]='h997
              40  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='hf4c, [1]='h57f
              50  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='h1a9, [1]='hf4c
              60  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='he0a, [1]='h1a9
              70  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='he5d, [1]='he0a
              80  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='h445, [1]='he5d
              90  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='h941, [1]='h445
             100  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='hbfc, [1]='h941
             110  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='h08b, [1]='hbfc
             120  OUTPUT_DATA [0]='hca1, [1]='h08b
```

Comment: This is what I also think. Thanks a lot for taking the time to test it yourself.

Comment: @shaiko: You're welcome.  Does this code work on your simulator?

Comment: With the above code I see the same problem.
But I was able to "solve" it by driving INPUT_DATA through a temporary signal and driving the internal logic with that temporary signal (instead of INPUT_DATA directly).
I'm pretty sure it's a simulation bug.

Comment: @shaiko, I have simulated it on Vivado simulator using the testbench code by toolic. The design works as intended. A bug in the simulator is very unlikely, unless you can share the version of the simulator you have used. If there is a bug, we should report it on Xilinx's forums.